# React input text box loses focus after typing a character

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, react-hooks

I see this is a common question but can't figure out the solution from the other answers because they don't follow the same process I have. This is a follow on to my original question: [useState variable not holding its state during onChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949385/usestate-variable-not-holding-its-state-during-onchange-event).

Basically every time I type a character the popUp is re-rendering causing the input box to lose focus.

```
const App() {

  const [units, setUnits] = useState('');
  const [showPopUp, setShowPopUp] = useState(false);
  const [teamState, setTeamState] = useState(null);
  const [lineState, setLineState] = useState(null);
  ...

function PopUp() {

    return (
      <div id="popUp" className={popUpStyle}>
        <div className="pop-up-bg"> </div>
        <div className="pop-up">
          <img className='close-button' src={closeButton} onClick={hpu} />
          {teamState && lineState && betslip(teamState, lineState)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }


  function handleChange(event) {
    setUnits(event.target.value)
  }

  const betslip = (team, line) =>
    (
      <div className='betslip'>
        <h1 className="betslip-header">Betslip</h1>
        <div >
          <table className="betslip-table">
            <tr>
              <th>Team</th>
              <th>Line</th>
              <th>Unit(s)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr >
              <td className='betslip-td'>{team}</td>
              <td className='betslip-td'>{linePlusMinus(line)}</td>
              <td className='betslip-td'>
                <div className='unit-div'>
                  <input type='text' className='unit-input' onChange={e => setUnits(e.target.value)} value={units}/>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
         <table className="betslip-table">
            <tr>
              <th>Risk</th>
              <td className='betslip-td'>{units}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Reward</th>
              <td className='betslip-td'>{reward(units, line)}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    );

  function spu(team, line){
    setTeamState(team);
    setLineState(line);
    setPopUpHtml(betslip(teamState, lineState));
    setShowPopUp(true);
  }

    function hpu(){
    setShowPopUp(false);
  }

...
return( 
<div className="container">
       { showPopUp && <PopUp />}
...
)}
```

Comment: You can try adding const [units, setUnits] = useState(''); inside bestLip component, which is a separate component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try isolating Betslip:

```
const betslip = (team, line) =>{
const [units, setUnits] = useState('');

return <div className='betslip'>
   
<h1 className="betslip-header">Betslip</h1>
    <div >
      <table className="betslip-table">
        <tr>
          <th>Team</th>
          <th>Line</th>
          <th>Unit(s)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td className='betslip-td'>{team}</td>
          <td className='betslip-td'>{linePlusMinus(line)}</td>
          <td className='betslip-td'>
            <div className='unit-div'>
              <input type='text' className='unit-input' onChange={e => setUnits(e.target.value)} value={units}/>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     <table className="betslip-table">
        <tr>
          <th>Risk</th>
          <td className='betslip-td'>{units}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Reward</th>
          <td className='betslip-td'>{reward(units, line)}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Edit: So you can try separating getLips() as an isolated component and not sharing the state with any other component. As far I saw, units are only being used by Betslip

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation.

Comment: betslip is not a react component so I cannot define a useState in it

Comment: So I made Betslip a react function, put the useState in it, then called that react component in the PopUp component passing it teamState and lineState and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Cool! Yes, its a react component, if you have a function that returns a Reactnode.